# 'Checkout' object is not iterable

Tags: html, django

I'm having a problem and here's my code please help.
I did this because what i want is when an existing user login the details of that user automatically appears on the page

error

> 'Checkout' object is not iterable
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout1/1/
>
> Django Version:   1.8.7
>
> Exception Type:   TypeError
>
> Exception Value: 'Checkout' object is not iterable
>
> Exception Location:   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 161

models

```
class Checkout(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fname
```

views

```
def checkout1(request, id):
    i = Checkout.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'checkout1.html',{'k':i})
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for i in k %}    
        {{i.fname}}
        {{i.address}}
        {{i.number}}
        {{i.city}}
        {{i.email}}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you getting a traceback `'Checkout' object is not iterable` because you using a single object:

```
>>> i = Checkout.objects.get(id=id)
>>> i
<Checkout: lorem ipsum> # single object
>>>
>>> i.address
'Mexico City'
>>> i.number
1239
>>>
```

If you work in the template with single object should:

```
{{ k.fname }}
{{ k.address }}
...
```

But if you using queryset objects, example:

```
>>> i = Checkout.objects.all()
>>> i
<QuerySet [<Checkout: lorem ipsum>, <Checkout: dolor ismet>]> # queryset objects
>>>
```

now in the template you can iterate it with `{% for` loop.